# Stiff system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I'm trying to solve a system of differential equations with `NDSolve`, but I get the error message:

> NDSolve::ndsz: At lnP == -21.0018, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

The core of the program is:

```
DiffEqs := If[Pb0OverP0 != 1, {
lnPb'[lnP] == dlnPbdlnP[lnP],
m'[lnP] == dmadimdlnP[lnP],
r'[lnP] == dradimdlnP[lnP]
}, {
(*lnPb'[lnP]\[Equal]dlnPbdlnP[lnP],*)
m'[lnP] == dmadimdlnP[lnP],
r'[lnP] == dradimdlnP[lnP]
}];
CentralValues := If[Pb0OverP0 != 1, {
 lnPb[#] == # + Log[Pb0OverP0],
 r[#] == 
  Sqrt[(4.*RhoSung*(10^-8)(*(1-Exp[#])*))/(
   3.*((ϵb[#] + ϵd[#]) + 
      PcentralGeo*Exp[#])(*Exp[#]*))],
 m[#] ==(*(4. π)/3 *)
  r[#]^3/RhoSung *(ϵb[#] + ϵd[#])
 }, {

 r[#] == 
  Sqrt[(3*10^(-8))/(RSg^2*(ϵb[#] + 
        PcentralGeo*Exp[#])*(ϵb[#] + 
        3*PcentralGeo*Exp[#]) (-λ + (4 π)/
        PcentralGeo))],
 m[#] ==(*(4. π)/3 *)
  r[#]^3/RhoSung *(ϵb[#] + ϵd[#])
 }] &;
NDSolveOptions = {MaxSteps -> Infinity,AccuracyGoal -> 10,PrecisionGoal -> 10,
       Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching",Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}};  
allsol = If[Pb0OverP0 != 1, 
 NDSolve[Flatten[{DiffEqs[#], CentralValues[#]}], {m, r, 
   lnPb}, {lnP, #, LnPMin}, Sequence@NDSolveOptions],
 NDSolve[
  Flatten[{DiffEqs, CentralValues[#]}], {m, r}, {lnP, #, LnPMin}, 
  Sequence@NDSolveOptions]] & /@ LnP0List;
```

With

```
Pb0OverP0=0.855924,logPc=-20.4569,PcentralGeo=1.3052*10^-9,λ=0
    LnP0List={0., -0.0921034, -0.184207, -0.27631, -0.368414, -0.460517, -0.55262, \
-0.644724, -0.736827, -0.828931, -0.921034, -1.01314, -1.10524, \
-1.19734, -1.28945, -1.38155, -1.47365, -1.56576, -1.65786, -1.74996, \
-1.84207, -1.93417, -2.02627, -2.11838, -2.21048, -2.30259, -2.39469, \
-2.48679, -2.5789, -2.671, -2.7631, -2.85521, -2.94731, -3.03941, \
-3.13152, -3.22362, -3.31572, -3.40783, -3.49993, -3.59203, -3.68414, \
-3.77624, -3.86834, -3.96045, -4.05255, -4.14465, -4.23676, -4.32886, \
-4.42096, -4.51307, -4.60517},LnPMin=-64.918,RhoSung=1.37*10^-8
```

Essentially, the parameters `RhoSung`, `PcentralGeo`, and `PbarcentralGeo` are used to avoid having to deal with too large numbers. `logPc` is the logarithm of `PcentralGeo`.

The Equations are:

```
    dlnPbdlnP[lnP_] = 
 Exp[lnP + logPc]/
  Exp[lnPb[lnP] + logPbc] ((ϵb[lnP] + 
    Exp[lnPb[lnP] + logPbc])/((ϵb[lnP] + ϵd[lnP]) + 
    Exp[lnP + logPc]))  

dmadimdlnP[lnP_] = 
 Exp[lnP]*3/RhoSung*(ϵb[lnP] + ϵd[lnP])*
  r[lnP]^2/(((ϵb[lnP] + ϵd[lnP]) + 
       PcentralGeo*Exp[lnP])/(
      2*r[lnP] (m[lnP] - r[lnP]))*(m[lnP]/PcentralGeo + (
        3*Exp[lnP]*(r[lnP])^3)/RhoSung) + 
     2/r[lnP]*(PtFunc[lnP] - Exp[lnP]*PcentralGeo))

dradimdlnP[lnP_] = 
 dmadimdlnP[
   lnP]/(3/RhoSung*(ϵb[lnP] + ϵd[lnP])*r[lnP]^2)
```

Lastly `ϵb` and `ϵd` are defined by interpolating a given table of values. `ϵb[lnP]` ranges from 10^-10 to 10^-21 when `lnP` varies from 0 to -64, namely

```
ϵb[lnP_] = 
 If[Pb0OverP0 != 1, ϵOfLnPScale[
   lnPb[lnP]], ϵOfLnPScale[lnP]]
ϵd[lnP_] = 
 If[Pb0OverP0 != 1, ϵOfLnPScale[
   Log[Exp[lnP] - Exp[lnPb[lnP]]]], 0]
```

With other tables, `NDSolve` works, but for some reason with the parameters given above it dosen't work.

Comment: I forgot that PtFunc is equal to Exp[lnP]*PcentralGeo if \[Lambda] is 0

Comment: I tried the simplest version, that is the one with PbOverP=0 and everything works, so I think the problem is in `dlnPbdlnP[lnP_] = 
 Exp[lnP + logPc]/
  Exp[lnPb[lnP] + logPbc] ((\[Epsilon]b[lnP] + 
    Exp[lnPb[lnP] + logPbc])/((\[Epsilon]b[lnP] + \[Epsilon]d[lnP]) + 
    Exp[lnP + logPc]))`